# bash XHTML parsing using xpath

Tags: bash, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm writing a small script to learn how to parse an XHTML web page. The following command:

```
cat q?s=goog.xhtml | xpath '//span[@id="yfs_l10_goog"]'
```

returns:

```
Found 2 nodes:
-- NODE --
<span id="yfs_l10_goog">624.50</span>-- NODE --
<span id="yfs_l10_goog">624.50</span>
```

How do I:

- need to write my command in order to only extract the value `624.50` ?
- what do I need to do to extract it only once ?

source page I'm parsing: http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog

Comment: This is more of an xpath question, isn't it?

Comment: yes indeed. I would like to get it working using xpath

Comment: updated post title to be clearer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

Give this a try:

```
xpath -q -e '//span[@id="yfs_l10_goog"][1]/text()'
```

**Edit:**

Pipe your output through:

```
sed -n '/span/{s/<span[^<]*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/;p;q}'
```

**Original answer:**

Using [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
echo -e '<foo><span id="yfs_l10_goog">624.50</span>\n<bar>xyz</bar><span id="yfs_l10_goog">555.50</span>\n<span id="yfs_l10_goog">123.50</span></foo>' | 
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//span[@id='yfs_l10_goog']"
```

Result of query:

```
624.50
```

Result of `echo`:

```
<foo><span id="yfs_l10_goog">624.50</span>
<bar>xyz</bar><span id="yfs_l10_goog">555.50</span>
<span id="yfs_l10_goog">123.50</span></foo>
```

Result of `xml fo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <span id="yfs_l10_goog">624.50</span>
  <bar>xyz</bar>
  <span id="yfs_l10_goog">555.50</span>
  <span id="yfs_l10_goog">123.50</span>
</foo>
```

Other queries:

```
$ echo -e '...' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//span[@id='yfs_l10_goog'][1]"
624.50
$ echo -e '...' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//span[@id='yfs_l10_goog'][3]"
123.50
$ echo -e '...' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//span[@id='yfs_l10_goog'][last()]"
123.50
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, i wish to use xpath.

Comment: @Baba: I think that utility has only very basic functionality. See my edited answer.

Comment: hmm, I believe xpath allows to be more direct by selecting nodes. w3schools have some examples but i have trouble simplifying them to match my requirements: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: getting: Cannot open file '-q' at /usr/share/perl5/XML/XPath.pm line 53.  not sure what it means

Comment: @Baba: Your version seems to be different than mine. Try it without the `-q` (and possibly without the `-e`).

Comment: Hi Dennis, yes appending /text() works. thanks! i still get the two spans but i'll figure it out

Comment: @Baba: Did you add the `[1]`? That should select only the first match.

Comment: got it :) cat q?s=goog.xhtml | xpath '(//span[@id="yfs_l10_goog"])[1]/text()'   thanks for your help!

Comment: @raoulbia I just had the same problem at it looks like an OSX issue https://github.com/michaelw/mediathek-dl/issues/1