# XML Parsing with Xpath(?) for certain value

Tags: bash, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm needing to parse a particular set of XML files for a value.

In this instance, I need to find every access id for `<group>THISGROUP</group>` with `<permission>WRITE</permission>`

In the example below, I would need `VX-3422867` returned. Also, I need to be able to accomplish this within a bash script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AccessControlListDocument>
    <access id="VX-3422867">
        <loc>http://localhost:8080/API/item/VX-410070/access/VX-3422867</loc>
        <grantor>admin</grantor>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
        <permission>WRITE</permission>
        <group>THISGROUP</group>
    </access>
        <access id="VX-3422866">
        <loc>http://localhost:8080/API/item/VX-410070/access/VX-3422866</loc>
        <grantor>admin</grantor>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
        <permission>NONE</permission>
        <operation>
            <shape>
                <tag>original</tag>
            </shape>
        </operation>
        <group>THISGROUP</group>
    </access>
    <access id="VX-3422865">
        <loc>http://localhost:8080/API/item/VX-410070/access/VX-3422865</loc>
        <grantor>admin</grantor>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
        <permission>WRITE</permission>
        <group>TWO</group>
    </access>
    <access id="VX-3422869">
        <loc>http://localhost:8080/API/item/VX-410070/access/VX-3422869</loc>
        <grantor>admin</grantor>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
        <permission>ALL</permission>
        <group>THREE</group>
    </access>
    <access id="VX-3422868">
        <loc>http://localhost:8080/API/item/VX-410070/access/VX-3422868</loc>
        <grantor>admin</grantor>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
        <permission>ALL</permission>
        <group>FOUR</group>
    </access>
    <access id="VX-975588">
        <loc>http://localhost:8080/API/item/VX-410070/access/VX-975588</loc>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
        <permission>OWNER</permission>
        <user>user-one</user>
    </access>
</AccessControlListDocument>
```

Comment: You have a lot of reading to do, methinks. You should start perhaps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984689/bash-xhtml-parsing-using-xpath).

Comment: BTW, "this is my input, please write a program for me that gives me the output I want" is a subcategory of "please do my work for me", which is not particularly welcome here -- hence the downvotes. Making an effort to at least show what you've tried or considered is helpful.

Comment: at least he gave input and output ;-/ Good luck to all.

Comment: My apologies for not explaining everything I had tried. I'm sure you understand being in a pinch and needing help.

Answer (score 2):

To print the IDs for all access entries with groups THISGROUP and permission WRITE:

```
xmlstarlet sel \
  -t -m '//access[group="THISGROUP"][permission="WRITE"]' \
  -v @id -n <in.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the `@id` attributes of the access elements who's `group` element value is equal to 'THISGROUP' and `permission` element value is equal to 'WRITE' with the following XPath:

```
/AccessControlListDocument/access[group = 'THISGROUP' and permission='WRITE']/@id
```

As for executing in a bash script, you could look at using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/AccessControlListDocument/access[group = 'THISGROUP' and permission='WRITE']/@id" myFile.xml
```

Or with a variety of other options (xmllint, saxon-lint, saxon, python, xidel) as suggested in answers to [How to execute XPath one-liners from shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell)

Comment: Thank you, I'm used to using Xidel. Turns out I was close to the syntax I needed, but not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

whith xpath:

If you wanna only de first id atribute:

```
   <xsl:value-of select="/AccessControlListDocument/access[child::group='THISGROUP' and child::permission='WRITE']/@id"/>
```

If you wanna every id atribute whit that condition:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/AccessControlListDocument/access[child::group='THISGROUP' and child::permission='WRITE']">
<xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This means get the "**id**" atribute from "**access**" node child from "**AccessControlListDocument**" parent, where "**access**" node have children nodes "**group**" with value 'THISGROUP' and node "**permission**" with value 'WRITE'.

Comment: This is actually a very good approach, as people are more likely to have xsltproc than they are to have xmlstarlet or an xmllint recent enough to have `--xpath`. You should perhaps show how to run it from bash, though.

Comment: I'd also suggest describing it as "With XSLT" rather than "with XPath".