# How to obtain contents of multiple HTML tags using grep?

Tags: html, bash, grep

I am trying to return the song name and artist from a webpage using a bash script.

After consulting some SO posts, I put together:

```
#!/bin/sh

metadata=$(curl -s marci277.marci.io |
  grep -oP '(?<=<p class="title"> ).*?(?= </div>)')

echo $metadata
```

However, it is simply returning a blank empty line.

Here is the relevant code from the webpage at this instant:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="block1" style="display:block;min-height:114px;width:100%;background:#ffff00;border-top:0px solid #000;border-bottom:0px solid #000;">
    <div id="letterbox1" class="letterboxThumbnail base" data-artist="Tom Robinson" data-title="Listen To The Radio" data-album="" data-thumbBGColor="ffffff" >
        <img src="img/artists/cache/mThumb_Tom Robinson.jpg" alt="Tom Robinson" width="104" height="104" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;" class="thumbnail" />
    </div>
    <p class="time">6:22 am  CST</p>
    <p class="title">Listen To The Radio</p>
    <p class="artist">Tom Robinson</p>
</div>
<p class="verticalSpacer"></p>
```

Only the 3rd and 2nd to last classes are of any use to me.

I also read somewhere that this grep technique might not work for non-divs (in this case, it's a p tag). If that's the case, how can I parse those tags for their attributes?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html or xml instead use some [specific tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994113/about-parsing-html-and-extract-data-using-shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can agree, if you really want to parse xml/html you should use a tool like `xpath` as described in this post: [bash XHTML parsing using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984689/bash-xhtml-parsing-using-xpath)

---

**Alternative way of solving your problem:**

I had a look on the code you've posted and the source code of `marci277.marci.io`. There is a ajax function embedded in the page that exactly provides what you are looking for. See code after `var xhr = $.ajax({...`

You can access it by using the following URL: http://marci277.marci.io/ajaxRequester.php?s=marci277

It provides the artist and title seperated by a `-` so parsing this in your shell script would be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
metadata=$(curl -s http://marci277.marci.io/ajaxRequester.php?s=marci277)
artist="$(echo $metadata | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" - "} {print $1}')"
title="$(echo $metadata | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" - "} {print $2}')"

echo "Artist: $artist"
echo "Title: $title"
```

Maybe this makes things easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution.

```
metadata="$(curl -s marci277.marci.io)"    
artist="$(sed -n 's@.*class="artist">\([^<]\+\).*@\1@p' <<< $metadata)"
title="$(sed -n 's@.*class="title">\([^<]\+\).*@\1@p' <<< $metadata)"
```